# Как использовать тернарный оператор, чтобы в cout ничего не выводилось?

Tags: c++

Есть инструкция вида `cout << (условие ? строка : ...)`.

Что нужно вставить вместо `...`, чтобы в консоль ничего не печаталось?

Comment: пустую строку например `""`

Comment: @Grundy а почему тогда `''` нельзя?

Comment: потому что в этом случае вы используете не строку, а [пустую знаковую константу, а это не допускается](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fhxwbt0t(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: @Grundy а пустая строка тогда из чего состоит?

Comment: не совсем понял вопрос, что значит _пустая строка тогда из чего состоит_?

Comment: Пустая строка есть группа символов в количестве 0. Символьная константа должна задавать **ровно один символ**. Она не может задавать 0 символов, или 15 символов, только 1. Поэтому `''` — невалидный синтаксис.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тернарный оператор требует чтобы выражения в обоих ветвях приводились к одному типу.
(Или если точнее, то второе выражение должно приводиться к первому)
Например `(условие ? "строка" : "")`
или `(условие ? std::string("строка") : "")`.